# BlackRaccoon while downloading a file giving error: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xcd609f0

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector, blackraccoon

I am using BlackRaccoon to download a file from FTP server. Following is the code:

```
- (IBAction)download:(id)sender {


    downloadData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity: 1];

    downloadFile = [[BRRequestDownload alloc] initWithDelegate: self];

    downloadFile.path = @"psnewsletter.pdf";
    downloadFile.hostname = @"server";
    downloadFile.username = @"user";
    downloadFile.password = @"pswd";

    [downloadFile start];  
}
```

Its gives following error

```
2014-02-20 11:48:43.526 BlackHillPrimarySchool[2036:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MainViewController requestFailed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xcd609f0'
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requestFailed:` is one of the `BRRequest` delegate method that you must implement in your view controller.

```
- (void)requestFailed:(BRRequest *)request {
    BRRequestError *reqError = request.error;
    // check the error, handle as needed.
}
```

I'm not sure how your code even compiled. This is a required method of the protocol.

Comment: It seems to be a bug in the initialiser: `- (instancetype)initWithDelegate:(id)delegate;` should be `- (instancetype)initWithDelegate:(id<BRRequestDelegate>)delegate;`

Comment: @Sebastian Good catch. That would be the problem.

Comment: I just submitted a bug report to the BlackRaccoon project to fix the type of the delegate parameter.